# How get selected value from drop-down list (Content control) using VBA in Word

Tags: vba, ms-word, combobox

I am new doing VBA in word, but use quite a lot in excel. I have a Content Control Combo box in my word document. I have names of employees to choose from, and the value I have set to their email address.
The idea is to send an email address to the person chosen from the combo box, by selecting a check box. I now how to do code to send the email when selecting the checkbox, but I am struggling with getting the Value (ie email address) from the combo box. All I want is a code that gives me the selected value from my combo box named "Reviewers". I need help with all the code, including how to DIM.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example, as a ContentControlOnExit macro that runs directly from your 'Reviewers' dropdown:

```
Private Sub Document_ContentControlOnExit(ByVal ContentControl As ContentControl, Cancel As Boolean)
Dim i As Long, StrEmail As String
With ContentControl
  If .Title = "Reviewers" Then
  For i = 1 To .DropdownListEntries.Count
    If .DropdownListEntries(i).Text = .Range.Text Then
      StrEmail = .DropdownListEntries(i).Value
      MsgBox StrEmail 
      Exit For
    End If
  Next
  End If
End With
End Sub
```

Alternatively, as a ContentControlOnExit macro that runs directly from a Checkbox titled 'Send Email':

```
Private Sub Document_ContentControlOnExit(ByVal CCtrl As ContentControl, Cancel As Boolean)
Dim i As Long, StrEmail As String
With CCtrl
  If .Title = "Send Email" Then
    If .Checked = True Then
      With .Parent.SelectContentControlsByTitle("Reviewers")(1)
        For i = 1 To .DropdownListEntries.Count
          If .DropdownListEntries(i).Text = .Range.Text Then
            StrEmail = .DropdownListEntries(i).Value
            MsgBox StrEmail
            Exit For
          End If
        Next
      End With
    End If
  End If
End With
End Sub
```