# How to get the text written in a Plain Text Content Control in Word via VBA

Tags: vba, text, ms-word, word-contentcontrol

I still haven't understood how to use VBA in Word. I have a Plain Text Content Control, where our employees will write some text. This text will be added to an email. But how do I get this text? I would like something like this:

```
preparerText = ActiveDocument.ContentControls("PreparerText").Range.Text
```

But it doesn't work.

I have tried to Google how to do this, but cannot find an answer (or perhaps the answer is there, but I just don't understand how to use it in my context)

Information about the content control I want to get text from:
[image: Information about the content control I want to get text from]

Comment: I already showed you how to do that in your other thread (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67356590/how-get-selected-value-from-drop-down-list-content-control-using-vba-in-word) - via .Range.Text! It really doesn't matter whether it's a plain text, rich text, dropdown, combobox, or date, content control, they're all read the same way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided your content controls have unique titles it can be as simple as:

```
preparerText = ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("PreparerText")(1).Range.Text
```

Comment: I've been doing it the hard way for many years it seems. Good one.

Comment: Thank you so much. I tried to look at the code you gave before, but I just couldn't get it to work. I forgot the (1).